# An exact solution to a homogeneous linear second order differential eq. with variable coefficients

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations

[Our differential equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAMRl.png)

Or in words: $$    \Bigg[\frac{\partial^2}{\partial u^2}  +\frac{h_+^2 \omega \sin(\omega u) \cos(\omega u)}{1-h_+^2\cos^2(\omega u)} \frac{\partial}{\partial u} + \frac{k_x^2 }{4(1+h_+ \cos(\omega u))}+ \frac{ k_y^2}{4(1-h_+ \cos(\omega u))} + \frac{m^2}{4}  \Bigg] \phi = 0$$

I got a particularly difficult equation from my project (for the interested: below this paragraph I explain how I got it). I have tried to rescale the equation with $e^{c(z)}$, with $c(z)$ a function of $z$. I also tried to do a coordinate transformation: $\cos(\omega u) = z$. Both of these didn't work and gave more singular points. I also tried brute forcing my way to the Heun's equation. But all to no avail. I'd really appreciate help!

I am working on a project where I try to find the wave operator for a real scalar field in a gravitational plus-polarized perturbed background. I used the Hamiltonian and mode operators $\phi$ and $\pi$.